# Blazor Wasm - Retaining state ready for a browser 'back' button press after link away

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I can browse a catalog of products with a category browser on the left and the list of products in category on the right.

When user selects a product, we link away to a product view page.

Now, when user presses back to return to catalog browser the active category is not retained.

I can fix that one easily by adding categoryId to the current url each time a category is selected so that when the user links away and then 'backs', we'll have the categoryId in the Url to auto select that category again.

However, what if I want to retain each category node's expanded / collapsed state?

- I could create a List, serialize it and add to current url each time a node is expanded or collapsed, but then that URL is getting pretty ugly.
- I could store the values in a state container service somewhere and add the id of that container record to the url, so i can retrieve it after a 'back', but then there's the issue that the user never presses back (navigates elsewhere instead) and I have a build-up of redundant state records.

What would be the most favourable pattern for this challenge?

Comment: One option you can consider is, You can create one single custom composite component with Category view and details view and switch between them without leaving the page.

Comment: Thanks.  That could work within a limited scope.  However, the Product View screen is fairly functionally interactive (not just a view) and can be linked to from other areas of my solution (e.g. stock reports) and not just from the Catalog browser I've mentioned in my question.  For these reasons, I'd prefer to make the Product View a routable component rather than just a utility component embedded into many other routable components.

Comment: You could store the page state in the browser session storage, this is self cleaning when the user closes the tab. You could also implement an in-memory cache - that would also clear when the session ends. You could implement a timeout for the stored state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design decision.  I would very likely choose your first option: I seek to encode into the URL enough info to identify the unique state of anything that I want  navigate to.  If I do this consistently in every page I make, it becomes much easier to build deep links, ensure back/forward history is right, and generally let the web work as it was intended.

As for the complexity of the URL, I try to make the simple things simple and the complicated things possible: default options and simple routing gets a simple URL, but I do not hesitate to let the URL grow for more complicated needs--for example, when arbitrary search filters/facets can be specified.

If the URL indeed grows to be impractically large (which is rare: even several thousand characters should be okay), then part of the state might need to be consolidated to an identifier that is stored in an API by which future API calls can look up the larger set of data they need.